# Insert the td tag value when checked in array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a table which has certain type of data and checkbox along with that. All i need is to insert the data of table into an array, only in the case when checkbox is checked. Here is my code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content" style="margin-top: 10em;">
<thead class="flip-content">
 <tr>
 <th class="hidden-print">Include</th>
 <th style="text-align: center;">Quantity</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Cost(USD)</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Markup(%)</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Markup Amount</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;color: #f00;" class="hidden-print">Your Profit(<?php echo $_SESSION['level_markup']; ?>%)</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Company Profit</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Price(USD)</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;">Price Per piece</th>
                            <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Actions</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody style="text-align: center;">
                        <?php
                        $x=0;
                        foreach($query_initial as $qurintl)
                        {

                            ?>
                            <tr class="hidden-print">
                             <td class="hidden-print"><input type="checkbox" value="" name="" id="checkbox1"></td>
                                <td> {{ quantity = <?php echo $qurintl['business_quantity']; ?> }} </td>
                                <td class="hidden-print"><input ng-model="basecost_<?php echo $x; ?>" ng-init="basecost_<?php echo $x; ?>=<?php echo $qurintl['business_final_price']; ?>" type="text" </td>
                                <td class="hidden-print"><input ng-model="markup_<?php echo $x; ?>" ng-init="markup_<?php echo $x; ?>=<?php echo $_POST['markupper']; ?>"></td>

                                <td class="hidden-print"> ${{ marukpamount = (basecost_<?php echo $x; ?> * markup_<?php echo $x; ?>) / 100 | number:2 }}</td>

                                <td class="hidden-print" style="color: #f00;"> ${{ yourprofit = (marukpamount * <?php echo $_SESSION['level_markup']; ?>) / 100 | number:2 }}</td>

                                <td class="hidden-print"> ${{ marukpamount - yourprofit | number:2 }}</td>

                                <td> ${{ results = basecost_<?php echo $x; ?> -- (basecost_<?php echo $x; ?> * markup_<?php echo $x; ?>) / 100 | number:0 }}</td>
                                <td>${{ results / quantity  | number:2 }}</td>
                                <td class="hidden-print"><input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="-"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            $x++;
                        }
                        ?>
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried so far. We are not going to write your code for you..

Comment: I am sorry @ShekharChikara but i am new to javascript, all i have done is searched everywhere and found nothing. Also if you don't want to write the code, please do not instead you can pass me any reference link or an overview about how to do this or to search this

Comment: Is this using AngularJS? If so, can you tag your question with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing angular with PHP, this is probably not the best way of solving your problem. You should add all your `$qurintl` to a javascript array and then build your table as follows:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.all = [{
    business_quantity: 3,
    business_final_price: 2,
    markupper: 5
  }, {
    business_quantity: 3,
    business_final_price: 3,
    markupper: 2
  }, {
    business_quantity: 3,
    business_final_price: 5,
    markupper: 4
  }];
  $scope.level_markup = 3;
  $scope.selected = [];
  $scope.actualize = function() {
    $scope.selected = $scope.all.filter(function(data) {
      return data.checked;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed flip-content" style="margin-top: 10em;">
    <thead class="flip-content">
      <tr>
        <th class="hidden-print">Include</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Quantity</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Cost(USD)</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Markup(%)</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Markup Amount</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;color: #f00;" class="hidden-print">Your Profit({{level_markup}}%)</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Optamark's Profit</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Price(USD)</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Price Per piece</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;" class="hidden-print">Actions</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="text-align: center;">
      <tr ng-repeat="data in all">
        <td class="hidden-print">
          <input ng-click="actualize();" ng-model="data.checked" type="checkbox">
        </td>
        <td>{{data.business_quantity}}</td>
        <td class="hidden-print">
          <input ng-model="data.business_final_price" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td class="hidden-print">
          <input ng-model="data.markupper">
        </td>

        <td class="hidden-print">${{ markupamount = data.business_final_price * data.markupper / 100 | number:2 }}</td>

        <td class="hidden-print" style="color: #f00;">${{ yourprofit = markupamount * level_markup / 100 | number:2 }}</td>

        <td class="hidden-print">${{ marukpamount - yourprofit | number:2 }}</td>
        <td>${{ results = data.business_final_price - (data.business_final_price * data.markupper) / 100 | number:0 }}</td>
        <td>${{ results / data.business_quantity | number:2 }}</td>
        <td class="hidden-print">
          <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" value="-">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>

    <div>Your Array: {{selected}}</div>
  </table>
</body>
```